# IVP with method of undetermined coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the given initial-value problem:
$$y'''-2y''+y'=2-24e^x+40 e^{5x}$$

$$y(0)=1/2, \ y'(0)=5/2,\  y''(0)=-13/2$$

The way I approached this was by solving for the roots of the left side of the equation ($r=0$ and $r=1$  with multiplicity $2$) and then finding the particular solutions of the right individually. I figured
$g(x)=2$ would have the solution 
$y(x)=a_0x$ , and by substituting this into my differential equation I solved that 
$a_0=2$ so $y=2x$. 
I went to repeat this step with $g(x)=-24e^x$ but the result I get is 
$a_0(2e^x-2e^x)=-24e^x.$ 
Is there a way around this or a different solution method?

Comment: Not sure how to change my formatting so that the equations appear in proper form, so sorry!

Comment: For the $e^x$ part, the problem is that $e^x$ is annihilated by the left side. So you multiply it by a large enough integer power of $x$ (2 in this case) so that it is no longer annihilated by the left side.

Comment: have you got the solution of the equation $$y'''-2y''+y'=0$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the third order non-homogeneous linear differential equation is given as follows 
$$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}=2-24e^x+40e^{5x}$$

Step 1: Finding auxiliary equation to the homogeneous differential equation of the above one!

The homogeneous differential equation is then,

$$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Auxiliary equation is $$m^3-2m^2+m=0$$

Continue,

$$m(m^2-2m+1)=0$$

$$m(m-1)^2=0$$

The complementary function is then,

$$y_c=c_1+c_2e^x+c_3xe^x$$

The undetermined coefficients is then,

$$S_1={1}$$

Seems like S1 repeats. Multiplying it with the lowest power of x.

$$S'_1={x}$$

$$S_2={e^x}$$

S2 repeats again, so doing the same thing

$$S'_2={x^2e^x}$$

$$S_3={e^{5x}}$$

The particular solution is then

$$y_p=Ax+Bx^2e^x+Ce^{5x}$$

Differentiating wrt x,

$$y'_p=A+2xBe^x+Bx^2e^x+5Ce^{5x}$$

$$y''_p=2Be^x+4xBe^x+Bx^2e^x+25Ce^{5x}$$

$$y'''_p=6Be^x+6xBe^x+Bx^2e^x+125Ce^{5x}$$

Putting what we get into the differential equation we have!

$$A=2$$

$$125C-2(25C)+5C=40$$

$$C=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$6B-2(2B)=-24$$

$$B=-12$$

So the general solution is

$$y=c_1+c_2e^x+c_3xe^x+2x-12x^2e^x+\frac{5}{2}e^{5x}$$

Given IVP, $$y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$c_1+c_2=-2$$

$$y'=c_2e^x+c_3e^x+c_3xe^x+2-12x^2e^x-24xe^x+\frac{25}{2}e^{5x}$$

$$y'(0)=\frac{5}{2}$$

$$c_2+c_3=-12$$

$$y''=c_2e^x+2c_3e^x+c_3xe^x-48xe^x-12x^2e^x-24e^x+\frac{125}{2}e^{5x}$$

Given

$$y(0)=\frac{-13}{2}$$

$$c_2+2c_3=-45$$

$c_3=-33$, $c_2=21$, $c_1=-23$

$$y=-23+21e^x-33xe^x+2x-12x^2e^x+\frac{5}{2}e^{5x}$$